# Remove the trailing commas at the first and last row only

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I am wondering how I can remove the trailing commas at the first and last row only (still keeping the other commas in there).

I found some similar questions but exactly the same.

Sample input:

```
000N5,DBS,103151201409220007770001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10,1256,19700802,,,,SMITH,,ABC,,1,,,,,,GX1 4NL,,  
10,1256,19690802,,,,WilliAM,,XX,,1,,,,,,Gl15 4MX,,  
101RN5,DBS,103151201409220007770001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Expected output:

```
000N5,DBS,103151201409220007770001
10,1256,19700802,,,,SMITH,,ABC,,1,,,,,,GX1 4NL,,  
10,1256,19690802,,,,WilliAM,,XX,,1,,,,,,Gl15 4MX,,
101RN5,DBS,103151201409220007770001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasonably easy in `sed`;

```sh
sed -i~ -e '1!{' -e '$!b' -e } -e 's/,*$//' filename
```

The braces select lines which are not the first (`1!`) and also not the last (`$!`) and skip `b` to the end of the script. For remaining lines, we proceed into the `s/.../.../` which replaces trailing commas with nothing.

The `-i~` option says to save the original as a backup in `filename~`; if you don't want to keep a backup, pass an empty string (how exactly is slightly platform-dependent; on BSD and MacOS, you need `-i ''` whereas on e.g. Linux you can simply omit the `''`).

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lpe 's/,+$// if $. == 1 || eof;' in_file > out_file
```

Or to edit the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -lpe 's/,+$// if $. == 1 || eof;' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)